# Не работает поиск максимального значения и минимального

Tags: c++

Исходной код программы:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int n = 15, N = 2 + n, M = 5 + n;
int main()
{
    double a[N][M],min,max;
    int i, j;
    i = j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <M; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = pow(n, i + j) + pow(n, i - j) - (i + j) * (i - j);
            if (i == 0 && j == 0) min = max=a[i][j];
            if (a[i][j] < min) min = a[i][j];
            if (a[i][j] > max) max = a[i][j]; 
            cout << "a[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << a[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "min = " << min << endl;
    cout << "max = " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я более чем уверен что я где-то затупил, но не знаю где и почему...

Задание:

Дано двумерный массив вещественных чисел a [i, j]. Заполнить его элементами по формуле: a [i, j] = n ^ (i + j) + n ^ (i-j) - (i + j) * (i-j), где i и j-индекс строк и столбцов элементов массива, которые вычисляются ао формулам: i = 2 + n, j = 5 + n, где n = 15.
Вывод на экран образован массив вместе с их именами в массиве. Найти и вывести сумму минимального и максимального элемента массива. Вывести значение минимального и максимального элемента массива.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102510/discussion-on-question-by-witalik-------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вот ответ после компиляции: min = 2 max = 1.45611e+41

Не после компиляции, а после выполнения.

Это правильный ответ. Вы же выводите в консоль все 340 значений. Найдите среди них самое маленькое и самое большое.

> Минимум должен быть:1.12227e+27. А максимум: 759400.

Хорошо бы объяснить, как Вы это определили.

Comment: Как минимум в консоль выводит всё значения и я так приближенно посмотрел возможно минимум не тот, но максимум тот
Я не могу понять почему максимум и минимум не тот что нужен выводиться. Что исправлять, как исправлять, почему...?

Answer (score 1):

Вынужден рисовать ответ, на вот этот вопрос -

> как понять что это за число (например: 1.45611e+41)

Если исходить из приведенного кода, то в матрице размером 17 на 20 (это понятно, откуда?) находятся элементы, вычисляемые следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно (надеюсь :)), что наибольшее значение достигается там, где максимально `i+j`, т.е. оно примерно равно (остальными членами можно пренебречь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не менее очевидно, что минимальное значение достигается там, где `i==j==0`, и равно оно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я смог ответить на ваш вопрос?

P.S. О том, что такое не посчитать на калькуляторе - да ну? 
Вот, на мобилке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот TheCalc, которым я обычно пользуюсь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но мне выводит число после знака равности, а весь массив не уместить в две строки с такими числами (в самом массиве 340 значений...).

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы Вам просто не дернуть

```
 std::minmax_element
```

Он вернет пару итераторов на мин и максимум

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    const uint64_t N{ 3 };
    double arr[N][N] = { {1.1, 2.2, -3.4},
                         {-100.95, 223.1, 0},
                         {300, -1999, 0} };

    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element(&arr[0][0], &arr[N - 1][N - 1]);

    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = std::string("Min : ") + std::to_string(*min);
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = std::string("Max : ") + std::to_string(*max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы попытался это использовать но в большинстве случаев я не трогаю то что мне не известно без теории, я только ±2 библиотеки подсоединяю и мне хватает. А вопросы задаю-потому что не могу найти в соответственном коде (или в голове) ошибку.

Comment: @Witalik cppref почитайте и все. Потихоньку будете увеличивать объём знаний. Писать велосипеды сейчас дорого и не нужно

Comment: Я понимаю, "modern C++" и все такое, но `std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n") = ...;` вместо `std::cout << ... << '\n'` - перебор. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat каждый *** как хочет )

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вы по нескольку раз используете инициализацию i и j. Можно просто написать :

```
int i=j;
```

И дальше в циклах просто писать:

```
for (i = 0; i <N; i++)
```

Comment: Я как бы всё понимаю. Но вы этого не понимаете. Это двухмерной массив тоисть i=0; j=0; a=1 ...i=0; j=n; a=n. Тоисть лучше удалите эту безсмислицу. Это не будет соответствовать двухмерному массиву.